# как в js прописать чтоб выбирало в каждом меню что-то одно и заливало другим цветом фон ячейки?

Tags: javascript

Как дописать в коде js чтоб в Списке 1 можно было выбирать только один подпункт 1 и выбранная ячейка подсвечивала другим цветом и параллельно, чтоб можно было делать выбор в списке 2 только один пункт с...

https://jsfiddle.net/Alexboo/tkwkpq8r/5/

Нашел скрипт, но НЕ получается его применить.....

```
$("#selectBackground ul li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#selectBackground ul li a").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Вот ссылка на этот скрипт в [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alexboo/UeML6/496/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно ограничить набор взаимоисключающих элементов, членами того же самого списка:

```
$("#selectBackground ul li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("ul").find("li a").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tkwkpq8r/6/